# How to use bower-art-resolver with specific version

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, npm-install, npm-package

We are using Jfrog Artifactory for dependency management and to store artifacts.

Using below bowerrc configuration/file  to install the npm modules to build Angular applications

```
echo '{' > .bowerrc
echo '   "registry": "http://${ArtifactoryCredentials}@artifactoryhost/artifactory/api/bower/bower",' >> .bowerrc
echo '   "search": [ "http://${ArtifactoryCredentials}@artifactoryhost/artifactory/api/bower/bower" ],' >> .bowerrc
echo '   "resolvers":["bower-art-resolver"],' >> .bowerrc
echo '   "proxy": "http://${ArtifactoryCredentials}@artifactoryhost/artifactory/api/bower/bower",' >> .bowerrc
echo '   "http-proxy": "http://${ArtifactoryCredentials}@artifactoryhost/artifactory/api/bower/bower",' >> .bowerrc
echo '   "https-proxy": "http://${ArtifactoryCredentials}@artifactoryhost/artifactory/api/bower/bower",' >> .bowerrc
echo '   "directory": "vendor"' >> .bowerrc
echo '}' >> .bowerrc
npm install bower-art-resolver
```

Since we are not mentioning  any version for bower-art-resolver, its trying to pull the latest node modules and installing them,

**The latest one:**

```
"@types/node": {
  "version": "20.2.5",
"resolved": "http://artifactoryserver/artifactory/api/npm/npm/@types/node/-/node-20.2.5.tgz",
"integrity": "sha1-********************/vs=",
"dev": true
 }
```

We would like to use below dependencies instead of 20.2.5. Is it possible to specify a version for bower-art-resolver in resolvers?

```
"@types/node": {
"version": "20.2.3",
"resolved": "http://artifactoryserver/artifactory/api/npm/npm/@types/node/-/node-20.2.3.tgz",
"integrity": "sha1-********************/vs=",
"dev": true
 }
```